# Not able to Read Javascript Object passed from LWC to Apex Method

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, wrapper-class

I would like to the read the Javascript Object response passed from LWC to Apex Method.

I have a requirement where SAP_Account__c custom object there exist a quantity 'Variable Quantity' field which I'm displaying in the lightning datable using wrapper received from apex. I would need to perform DML on this field based on the user input.

Please find the object Which I'm passing from LWC to Apex:

```
LWC Method: 

    handleSave(event) {
     
    this.saveDraftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
            this.isLoading = true;
    
            //Construct the wrapper 
            let sapAccountRecordData = {
                selectedSapAccounts : this.selectedSapAccounts,
                recordId : this.recordId, 
                variableQuantity : this.saveDraftValues
            }; 
    
    updateQuantity({ record: sapAccountRecordData })
            .then((result) => {
    
                if(result.responseCode === 'Success'){
                    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Annual Volume Updated Successfully',
                        variant: 'Success'
                    });
                    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
                }
                     
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.isLoading = false;
            });
    
    }

Apex Method: 

    public static void updateQuantity(SelectedSAPAccountResponse record){
            
             System.debug('record----->' + record); //Need help here ----> Record is not printed in the debug
I would need help here to read record and compare changed variableQuantities to update custom SAP_Account__c record. 
             
             List<SelectedSAPAccountResponse> wrapperResponseList = new List<SelectedSAPAccountResponse>(); 
             SelectedSAPAccountResponse wrapperObj;
    }

Apex Class : Created class as per the Javascript Object datatypes: 

public class SelectedSAPAccountResponse {
    
@AuraEnabled public String recordId { get; set; } 
    
    @AuraEnabled public SelectedSAPAccounts[] selectedSAPAccounts { get; set; }
    
    @AuraEnabled public List<VariableQuantity> variableQuantities { get; set; }
     
    public SelectedSAPAccountResponse(String recordId, SelectedSAPAccounts[] selectedSAPAccounts, List<VariableQuantity> variableQuantities){
        this.recordId = recordId; 
        this.selectedSAPAccounts = selectedSAPAccounts;
        this.variableQuantities = variableQuantities;
    }        
}

public class SelectedSAPAccounts {
    @AuraEnabled public String sapAccname { get; set; }
    
    @AuraEnabled public String sapAccId { get; set; }
    
    @AuraEnabled public String sapAccount { get; set; }
    
    @AuraEnabled public Integer sapAccountNumber { get; set; }
    
    @AuraEnabled public Double sapAccVariableQuantity { get; set; }
    
    @AuraEnabled public Double splitQuantityValue { get; set; }
    
    public SelectedSAPAccounts(String sapAccname, String sapAccId, String sapAccount, Integer sapAccountNumber, Double sapAccVariableQuantity, Double splitQuantityValue){
        
        this.sapAccname = sapAccname;
        this.sapAccId = sapAccId;
        this.sapAccount = sapAccount;
        this.sapAccountNumber = sapAccountNumber;
        this.sapAccVariableQuantity = sapAccVariableQuantity;
        this.splitQuantityValue = splitQuantityValue;
    }
    
}

public class VariableQuantity {
    @AuraEnabled public String Id { get; set; } 
    @AuraEnabled public Double sapAccVariableQuantity { get; set; }
    
    public VariableQuantity(String Id, Double sapAccVariableQuantity){
        this.Id = Id; 
        this.sapAccVariableQuantity = sapAccVariableQuantity; 
    }
}
                 
    //Changed sapAccVariableQuantity value is 20 received from draft values and old value was 10. I would need to update value to 20 and save on the record. 
                                
Please find the wrapper object received from javascript to apex method.    
                
record----->{"selectedSapAccounts":"[{\"sapAccname\":\"Test SAP Account\",\"sapAccId\":\"a0559000001HRIuAAO\",\"sapAccountNumber\":\"0000331651\",\"sapAccVariableQuantity\":10,\"splitQuantityValue\":50,\"sapAccount\":\"/a0559000001HRIuAAO\"}]","recordId":"00k59000004CBJjAAO","variableQuantity":[{"sapAccVariableQuantity":"20","Id":"row-0"}]}
        
Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you
```

Comment: You can have apex classes for parameters that the LWC passes without all this messing around with JSON serialize/deserialize. Just make sure you define your Apex class with properties of the required types and with the names as set in the LWC. You can then access all these values in the normal way in your Apex code.

Comment: Thank you @PhilW for your response.
 I have created apex class 'SelectedSAPAccountResponse' based on your suggestion. I'm getting error "System.JSONException: Expected List<SelectedSAPAccountResponse.SelectedSAPAccounts>"  
Would you please suggest where I'm going wrong. 
Changed sapAccVariableQuantity value is 20 received from draft values and old value was 10. I would need to know the suggestions to update value to 20 and save on the record 'SAP_Account__c'. 

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are you stringifying the value? You can pass objects directly to Apex as long as you have an appropriately defined apex class with aura-enabled public properties.

Comment: Sure @PhilW Thank you. Please let me try without sringifying the value.

Comment: @PhilW I changed my code but still getting the same exception. Please find the code.

Comment: Change `updateQuantity` to accept a `SelectedSAPAccountResponse`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145725/discussion-between-rose-and-phil-w).

Comment: @PhilW Thank you for your response. As per your suggestion, I have changed the updateQuantity to accept SelectedSAPAccountResponse but now record is not printed in the debug.
Thank you for your time for looking after my query.

Comment: @PhilW I have updated my code as per your suggestion and now there exists top level class for selectedSAPAccounts & variableQuantity. But I'm still getting the record as null in the debug. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: @PhilW Thank you for your suggestion. I checked the JS code. Is it something that we cannot directly assign this.selectedSapAccounts & this.saveDraftValues

Do I need to construct a separate array for these two values.

Thank you.

Comment: You could try simplifying the data being passed, just to see if you can get data passing, then build up the complexity so you can do what you need to do. Not knowing quite how `this.selectedSapAccounts` and `this.saveDraftValues` are set I can't comment on whether these are appropriate.